# SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search (FTS) extremely slow when more than one CONTAINSTABLE in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search (FTS) is extremely slow in this scenario:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT [...] FROM ContentItem CI WHERE 
(**EXISTS** (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM **CONTAINSTABLE**([**Table1**], *, '"[search_string]*"') FT 
WHERE FT.[Key] = CI.ContentItem_Id)) 
ORDER BY [...]
```

**Results:** super fast on SQL 2005 and SQL 2008

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT [...] FROM ContentItem CI WHERE 
(**EXISTS** (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM **CONTAINSTABLE**([**Table2**], *, '"[search_string]*"') FT 
WHERE FT.[Key] = CI.ContentItem_Id)) 
ORDER BY [...]
```

**Results:** super fast on SQL 2005 and SQL 2008

**Query 3:**

```
SELECT [...] FROM ContentItem CI WHERE 
(**EXISTS** (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM **CONTAINSTABLE**([**Table1**], *, '"[search_string]*"') FT 
WHERE FT.[Key] = CI.ContentItem_Id) 
**OR EXISTS** (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM **CONTAINSTABLE**([**Table2**], *, '"[search_string]*"') FT 
WHERE FT.[Key] = CI.ContentItem_Id)) 
ORDER BY [...]
```

**Results:** super fast on SQL 2005 (about a second), **but extremely slow (3 min+) on SQL 2008**

I'm aware of performance issues  with SQL 2008 FTS (even on stackoverflow), but haven't find any reasonable solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Can you rewrite Query 3 to

```
SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS ... CONTAINSTABLE(Table1...)
UNION
SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS ... CONTAINSTABLE(Table2...)
ORDER BY ...
```

?

UNION ALL may be faster than UNION, but possibly result in duplicate records.

Answer (score 1):

You probably get a bad plan. If you can post plan, it will help diagnose the problem. In case a bad join was choose, you can use query hint to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We just upgraded to SQL 2008 and ran into this issue.  I found if I put this at the bottom of the query, it worked great for me: OPTION (MAXDOP 1)