# Sql Server 2008 Performance issue combinning CONTAINSTABLE and OR

Tags: sql-server-2008

Table_X Contains 7000 Rows
Table_Y Contains 1 000 000 Rows

This request is running fast on SQL Server2005 but take 3 minutes on SQL Server 2008

```
SELECT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]   
FROM [dbo].[TableX] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableY] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[Fk_Id]
WHERE (
    (
        [Extent2].[Fk_Id] IN (
            (
                SELECT [KEY]
                FROM CONTAINSTABLE([TableX], (Description), N'"PMI_Log"') [CT]
                )
            )
        )
    OR (
        [Extent2].[id] IN (
            (
                SELECT [KEY]
                FROM CONTAINSTABLE([TableY], (Description), N'"PMI_Log"') [CT]
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

Already rebuild the index, statistics and catalog.

The 2 subqueries (select..FROM ContainsTable...) take 15ms

The execution plan say that it takes 100% of time in Table Valued Function [FulltextMatch]

After lots of test, it happens that when I put a OR between to FullText queries, the performance are falling down.

Can someone help ?

thx,

This questions is clearly the same problem: [SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search (FTS) extremely slow when more than one CONTAINSTABLE in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063498/sql-server-2008-full-text-search-fts-extremely-slow-when-more-than-one-contain)

Comment: Also, if table_X contains 900 000 rows everything is runnning great...

Answer (score 2):

This was [a known issue](http://sqlking.wordpress.com/2010/06/06/slow-fulltext-query-performance-using-freetext-and-contains/) with SQL 2008 / 2008 R2. It was fixed in [2008 SP1 CU9](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2083921) and [2008 R2 CU4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2264562).

As a workaround, you can split your query into two and `UNION` the results.

```
SELECT 
   [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]   
FROM 
   [dbo].[TableX] AS [Extent1]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableY] AS [Extent2] 
   ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[Fk_Id]
WHERE
   [Extent2].[Fk_Id] IN 
   (
      SELECT [KEY]
      FROM CONTAINSTABLE([TableX], (Description), N'"PMI_Log"') [CT]
   )

UNION

SELECT 
   [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID]   
FROM 
   [dbo].[TableX] AS [Extent1]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableY] AS [Extent2] 
   ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[Fk_Id]
WHERE
   [Extent2].[Fk_Id] IN 
   (
      SELECT [KEY]
      FROM CONTAINSTABLE([TableY], (Description), N'"PMI_Log"') [CT]
   )
```